# How to ProxyPass if the request doesn't correspond to a file

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to implement the following behavior:
If the request corresponds to a file in `/var/www/html`, then serve it, else, ProxyPass to a different hostname and port.
I am aware of the `RewriteCond` directive and that we can exclude some path from a `ProxyPass` but that doesn't help me achieve what I want.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?